# Need to update from 18.04 to 20.04 but SU does not show this option

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, upgrade

I have Ubuntu 18.04 DELL laptop (where Ubuntu was preinstalled) with RTX 2060 GPU. I need to update its version to 20.04 but somehow (maybe it is too late Ubuntu 18.04 support ended in 2021 August) software updater does not show me this option (/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades set to normal)

```
~$ sudo do-release-upgrade -d -f DistUpgradeViewGtk3
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Upgrades to the development release are only 
available from the latest supported release.
```

So basically SU does not see update option.
What I should do in such situation to have smooth update from 18.04 to 20.04?

**UPDATE**

removing `-d` helped, but now

```
~$ sudo do-release-upgrade -f DistUpgradeViewGtk3
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
```

Maybe some updates I can skip?

Comment: You don't need `-d`. Run `do-release-upgrade`.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 is still supported. The support ends in April '23.

Comment: Just FYI, but [*flavors* of Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) come with only 3 years of support, which meant to April-2021 but the core of those systems (ie. packages from `main` that are common with Ubuntu Server/Ubuntu Desktop) came with 5 years of support, thus still have support.  You can confirm using `ubuntu-support-status` where you'll see what % of packages are still *supported*, even if *flavors* its considerable.  As Pilot6 already stated; `-d` is wrong as you don't want to move to the *development* release; ie. *kinetic* or 22.10 as 20.04 has been *stable* for some time

Comment: @guiverc According to my experience even EoL 3-year flavors can be upgraded to a new LTS without any problems, because there is no reason to fail.

Comment: @Pilot6 I think your comment about the d option is an answer.

Comment: @Pilot6 that was what I was trying to indicate.. We (as in *flavors*; wearing a flavor hat of mine) no longer support 18.04, **but** we do nothing to prevent upgrade whilst a release is EOL; yesterday I tested a *flavor* of 16.04 performing a *release-upgrade* just for a comment here  on what I believe is now a closed (*off-topic*) post; the [Ubuntu Release Upgrader tool](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader) is the same for all (and `ubuntu-support-status` will show that)..  I upvoted your comment; was trying to clarify the *possible* understanding the OP maybe had

Comment: I'm a bit nervous about the upgrade because it's my work machine, and it also has a rtx 2060 graphics card which I also use at work. At Ubuntu 16.04 I somehow had to manually install nvidia driver.

Comment: Why are you adding `DistUpgradeViewGtk3`?

Comment: If you are nervous, then *get prepared* for problems. Backup your data. Know how to reinstall every application that you need. Have your step-by-step troubleshooting and reinstall instructions for your graphics card printed out and on hand. Have an installation LiveUSB ready. Boot a 20.04 LiveUSB and test your hardware in the "Try Ubuntu" environment before trying to upgrade. Take time to *understand* what you need to do. Lots of ways to be prepared.

Comment: If you're using 18.04.5/6 LTS with the HWE kernel option; you're already using the GA kernel for 20.04 so you know they should work fine (ie. same kernel modules or *drivers* can be used for both...) but  you didn't say which kernel stack you're using, if both are installed (*what would be required for you to be using HWE on 18.04, upgrade then login with GA*) etc. I'd likely boot a *live* system and test it (as already suggested!). Look at what option(s) you're currently using on your existing install as release provides only partial details.

Comment: @guiverc 
```
~$ hostnamectl
   Static hostname: marat-g5
         Icon name: computer-laptop
           Chassis: laptop
  Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
            Kernel: Linux 5.4.0-120-generic
      Architecture: x86-64
```

Comment: 4.15 was the 18.04 GA kernel; you're using the GA kernel stack from 20.04 already, ie. 5.4  (which is available for 18.04 via use of HWE)...  ie. you know you should be good using the GA kernel from 20.04 as that's what you're using already... You can have both GA & HWE kernel stacks installed though; selecting at boot; what you provided only shows what you're currently running (ie. 18.04 with HWE kernel stack which uses the 20.04 GA kernel).  For details you could read https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack etc

Comment: You **must** install all upgrades before you can `do-release-upgrade` ; the [Ubuntu *release-upgrade* tool](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader) will prevent upgrading whilst you have upgrades needing to be applied.  Use `sudo apt full-upgrade` to apply all upgrades; `apt upgrade` can leave some not installed.. thus use `full-upgrade` as per the Upgrade instructions

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `-d` switch. It is to upgrade to a development release.

Run `do-release-upgrade`. It should work.

If you are asked to install all available updates, run

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

and try again

```
do-release-upgrade
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try it!